# mysql replace abc with xyz in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to replace "domain.com" with the servers hostname in a table.

Now I want to replace any lines that have domain.com with the servers hostname

I tried the following command but it doesn't work:

```
mysql --user=root --password=mypass homedata
UPDATE `names` SET `domain` = replace(domain, 'domain.com', '$(hostname)')
```

Also I guess it doesn't matter that some lines have something before domain.com for example xyzstackoverflow.com

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You made a pastebin file for 2 lines of code? Couldn't paste it here?

Comment: @HerrK *Calm down* - huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying it from a ¿bash script?. Try this way:

```
#! bin/bash
updatevar="UPDATE names SET domain = REPLACE(domain, 'domain.com', '$(hostname)');"
updatevar2="UPDATE names SET domain = REPLACE(domain, 'domain1.com', '$(hostname)');"

mysql --user=root --password=mypass homedata << eof 
$updatevar
$updatevar2
eof
```

Comment: How would I run two commands at the same time with this bash script?

Comment: That replaces domain.com with the hostname but I have other words that need replacing with the hostname

Comment: Thanks. That works however I have a question a little off topic. This doesn't work when I upload a file with these settings but works when I create it manually (vi) any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe the character set, the end of lines in the file, can be much options, but check this two options.